# magento 1.9 Navigation left side menu

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

Problem I'm having;

I'm trying to add a Left sidebar navigation but everytime I install an addon to do this it always ends up the top of the page and not the left (as in, under the menu but ABOVE the slideshow I have there). I've tried looking for a layout.xml and cannot find it in my directory anywhere. Very odd.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: Did you check your catalog.xml file in layout

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in there regarding a side menu. It seems to be setup as a 1 or 2 column, even though I changed it in the custom xml within the admin backend.

Comment: ok set 1 column left and call this <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Comment: under <catalog_category_default translate="label">

Comment: Just to confirm I add this to the catalog.xml file?

Comment: yes under this <catalog_category_default translate="label">

Comment: Just have to step out of the office for a few hours, will post back when I have results, thankyou very much.

Comment: it is working....

Answer (score 1):

You should use the layout 1 column left and add the code below under `<catalog_category_default translate="label">` in the catalog.xml file.

```
 <reference name="left"> 
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```